# SQL CSV import parasitic characters

Tags: mysql, csv, innodb

**My CSV file (sample) :**

```
;"=""VENTE""";2020/09/11;
;"=""IBH""";2020/09/15;
;"=""HGTPE""";2020/09/02;
```

**My sql query** :

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE siel_demo CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' optionally ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES`

**Result :**

[image: screenshot]

**But i want :**

[image]

After several tries, I cannot keep only the value without parasitic characters

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use actually InnoDB

Comment: The data has been loaded correctly and the values you see are those actually in the CSV. If you want some other format (based on the format I expect them coming from excel), you either need to export them differently (without formulas), modify the CSV after the export or modify the data after the import.

Comment: CSV data comes from software that cannot be configured. I have no choice but to do with this data. There must be a solution to ignore the "" or =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the csv, you can run an update query to remove the unwanted characters.

e.g. `UPDATE siel_demo SET grille = SUBSTR(grille, 3, LENGTH(grille) - 3) WHERE grille LIKE '="%"'`